# How can set delay between onPress

Tags: react-native

```
  <TouchableOpacity
    onPress={
    () => {
      Animated.timing(fadeAnim, {
      toValue: 0,
      duration: 300,
      useNativeDriver:false
    }).start();
    }}

    onPressIn={onPress}
  >
```

I want to add delay between 2 onPress. I want click TouchableOpacity and first run the onPress and after delay run the onPressIn.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better if you used Pressable instead of TouchableOpacity to fulfill your use case. Here is an example where you can set a timeout function to trigger 1 second after the button has been on pressed and released and perform whatever you want with the second onPress function.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Pressable, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  const [timesPressed, setTimesPressed] = useState(0);

  let textLog = '';
  if (timesPressed > 1) {
    textLog = timesPressed + 'x onPress';
  } else if (timesPressed > 0) {
    textLog = 'onPress';
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Pressable
        onPress={() => {
          setTimesPressed((current) => current + 1);
          setTimeout(() => {
            // do whatever you want here
          }, 1000);
        }}
        style={({ pressed }) => [
          {
            backgroundColor: pressed
              ? 'rgb(210, 230, 255)'
              : 'white'
          },
          styles.wrapperCustom
        ]}>
        {({ pressed }) => (
          <Text style={styles.text}>
            {pressed ? 'Pressed!' : 'Press Me'}
          </Text>
        )}
      </Pressable>
      <View style={styles.logBox}>
        <Text testID="pressable_press_console">{textLog}</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 16
  },
  wrapperCustom: {
    borderRadius: 8,
    padding: 6
  },
  logBox: {
    padding: 20,
    margin: 10,
    borderWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
    borderColor: '#f0f0f0',
    backgroundColor: '#f9f9f9'
  }
});

export default App;
```